# Подсказки при валидации формы + Kube css

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать, чтобы span error высвечивался если поле пустое и высвечивался span sucsess если поле заполнено?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, это реализуется далеко не на CSS3, а на JS. Вот пример реализации с использованием jQuery:

```js
$('input#foo').on('keyup', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (this.value.length === 0) {
    $('.success').hide();
    $('.error').show();
    $this.removeClass("active-success");
    $this.addClass("active-error");
  } else {
    $('.error').hide();
    $('.success').show();
    $this.removeClass('active-error');
    $this.addClass("active-success");
  }
});
```

```css
.active-error {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 4px #ed1c24;
}

.active-success {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 4px #22b14c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="foo">    
<span class="error" style="display: none;">Ошибка</span>
<span class="success" style="display: none;">Успешно</span>
```

Comment: на вашем месте я бы переименовал тему во что-то вроде "Подсказки при валидации формы". Так другим участникам форума будет легче найти ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как привязать цвет поля: error - красный, succsess-зеленый, по умолчанию - синий?

Comment: сейчас доработаю код

Comment: мой ответ вас чем-то не устроил?

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, не могли бы вы поставить ему + или пометить как "Верный"? Или может быть вам еще что-то не понятно?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все понятно, ответ очень помог